# Computing convergence rate of a standard normal rv

Tags: probability

Let X be a standard normal rv, and let a,b, $\epsilon$ > 0 and a - b > 0.
I'm trying to prove that

$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon^2 $log$ P( \| \epsilon X - a \| < b) = - \frac{(a - b)^2}{2}$

I have shown that  $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} P( \| \epsilon X - a \| < b) = 0$ by using the Chebyshev bounds, and now I am trying to use L'Hopital to finish the problem.

$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \frac{logP( \| \epsilon X - a \| < b) }{ \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} } = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \frac{\frac{d}{d\epsilon} logP(\| \epsilon X - a \| < b) }{ -\frac{1}{\epsilon^3} }$ (by L'Hopital)

$= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\epsilon f(\frac{a + b}{\epsilon}) (a+b) - \epsilon f(\frac{a+b}{\epsilon})(a - b)}{\phi(\frac{a + b}{\epsilon}) - \phi(\frac{a - b}{\epsilon})}$

However, as the last expression shows, the expression just seems to get more and more complicated as I repeatedly use L'Hopital. Note, also, in the last expression f is the pdf of X and $\phi$ is its cdf.